# How to give checkbox in select tag using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I created a table using javascript function as show below.
[image]

When I click on Add Row then the javascript function gets activated and it creates rows of textboxes. And the code is

```
function addRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
    var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
    var columnCount = table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
    element1.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
    element1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set the id attribute   
    element1.setAttribute('checked', true); //set checkbox by default checked  
    cell1.appendChild(element1); //append element to cell

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
    element2.setAttribute('name', 'sl' + rowCount);
    element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "textarea";
    element3.setAttribute('rows', '4');
    element3.setAttribute('cols', '40');
    element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
    element3.setAttribute('name', 'discription' + rowCount);
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
    element4.setAttribute('name', 'quantity' + rowCount);
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
    element5.setAttribute('name', 'price' + rowCount);
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
    element6.setAttribute('name', 'CST' + rowCount);
    element6.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var element7 = document.createElement("select");
    var optarr = ['vat1', 'vat2', 'vat3', 'vat4', 'vat5', 'vat6'];
    for (var i = 0; i < optarr.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = optarr[i];
        opt.value = optarr[i];
        opt.className = optarr[i];
        element7.appendChild(opt);
    }
    element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
    element7.setAttribute('name', 'tax' + rowCount);
    element7.setAttribute('value', 'vat5');
    cell7.appendChild(element7);
}
```

Now i need to replace the option of select tags with checkboxes.I tried using `document.createElement("checkbox")` but its not working.So how to create checkboxes instead of option.Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher   See what i need is when i click on "Add Row" function a row will come but that row should consists of select tag and inside select tag i should get checkboxes.If i write in html then it wont add on clicking "AddRow" function

Comment: You are not going to get the desired behavior out of the box.  the `option` element does not allow for having a checkbox in it.  You'll have to write something custom and the link provided is a good start.